# Solidity smart contract not returning correct value

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

I have the following function in an ERC20 solidity smart contract:

```
  function getSummary() public view returns (string, string, address, uint, uint){
    return(
      symbol,
      name,
      creator,
      balances[msg.sender],
      _totalSupply
      );
  }
```

When I call this function in remix I get a non zero balance for the account I'm on in metamask. That value is correct.
But when I call this function in a react next.js app the the balance returns a zero. Here is that code:

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
const account = accounts[0];
let tokenContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, props.query.address);
let tokenSummary = await tokenContract.methods.getSummary().call();
let balance = await tokenContract.methods.balanceOf(account).call();
console.log(tokenSummary);
```

When I console.log tokenSummary, the balance is 0. But then if I call balanceOf I get a non-zero value (which is correct). What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating solution from the comments to an answer</sub>

> Try `let tokenSummary = await tokenContract.methods.getSummary().call({from: account})`.
>
> `msg.sender` is the address of whoever initiated the transaction/call. If not specified in the transaction object, web3js will use the value in `web3.eth.defaultAccount` which is undefined by default. The end result of your code was that the value of `msg.sender`was `0x0`
>
> -- [Adam Kipnis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8474917/adam-kipnis); [Mar 9, 2018 at 19:55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200886/solidity-smart-contract-not-returning-correct-value#comment85407523_49200886) and [Mar 9, 2018 at 20:43](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200886/solidity-smart-contract-not-returning-correct-value#comment85408880_49200886)